# CSS inline-block elements not on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a series of inline-block divs, all with a width of 33%. They are supposed to form a grid - 3 divs per line. This works great except on the first line, where the first inline-block div takes up the whole line and its horizontal positioning is very strange. See for yourself:

http://restartcomputer.com/category/products/new-products/

Any ideas how this can be fixed??

Comment: try on `clearfix::after` change `display` to `hidden`

Comment: Can you post the code? And a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove or change the padding-bottom, if i try to remove it's work well

```
.products-breadcrumbs ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 90px;
    **padding-bottom: 25px;**
}
```

Comment: Talking about CSS on your sub-menu (iPod & iPad, mac...)

Comment: You're a genious!!! However did you figure that out? They seem completely unrelated to me.

Comment: thanks :) I'm not sure because i need to look at your code but it seems that your Divs with class "entry clearfix product-entry" can not go below with the submenu. you don't like Boostrap or Foundation ?

Comment: I use a good and simple reset CSS whan i start a new proect : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ It is the best and no bad surprise with it ;)

Comment: I am making some modifications to an already-established website. Most of this code is not mine so I have to do a bit of detective work sometimes.